# Multi-threaded database read access

Tags: multithreading

I have a process(c++ code) that reads and writes from database (Oracle).
But it takes long time for process to finish.

I was thinking of creating partitions in the tables that this process queries. 
And then making the process multi-threaded so that each thread(one for each partition) can read/write the data in parallel.

I will be creating a DB connection per thread.

Will `write` slow it down?
Will this work? 
Is there any other way of improving performance (all queries are tuned and optimized already)?

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: It's impossible to say, without knowing the performance profile of the current system. Where does the time go, currently? It could be waiting for data, processing data, waiting for write transactions to commit, or somewhere else. This will largely determine the appropriate solution.

Comment: I have posted this again with some details. May be you can help me now :)

Answer (score 0):

If the current bottleneck is writing the data to the database then creating more threads to write more data may or may not help, depending on how the data is partitioned, and whether or not the writes can occur concurrently, or whether they interfere with each other (either at the database lock level, or at the database disk IO level).

Creating more threads will instead allow the application to process more data, and queue it up for writing to the database, assuming that there is sufficient hardware concurrency (e.g. on a multicore machine) to handle the additional threads.

Partitioning may improve the database performance, as may changing the indexes on the relevant tables. If you can put separate partitions on separate physical disks then that can improve IO when only one partition needs to be accessed by a given SQL statement.

Dropping indexes that aren't needed, changing the order of index columns to match the queries, and even changing the index type can also improve performance.

As with everything: profile it before and after every proposed change.