# Database access in parallel threads , viable option?

Tags: c++, database, multithreading, oracle11g

I have the following situation

```
main()
{

   hnd = CreateTHread( func1 );

   // Call fun2()

   wait(hnd);

   return ;

}


fun2()
{
  //Access database to perform some read operation on TAble A
}


func1()
{

//Access database to perform some read operation on TAble A
// Recursive operations
}
```

What I observed is, `fun2()` takes a longer duration to complete if I use threading approach. Could it be since the THread func and fuc2 are working on the same table. Note, there is only a read operation in both the functions. The AWR report suggested , number of query exectutions increased when the threading approach was used

Comment: You forgot to mention the most important thing here? what's the database and what driver you are using? does your DB driver do simultaneous requests or acts like a queue? do you access it through a single connection?

Comment: @yy_H I am using oracle 11G as my database . I start a seperate transaction for the thread .How do I check if DB driver do simultaneous requests ?

Comment: if the docs doesn't say create a long running requests and try to run a simultaneous request.

Comment: Oracle docs on concurrency http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm

Comment: Are you using Oracle Client, or a direct connection?

Comment: @Boris Yes I am using a oracle client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question - [Multi-threaded database read access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989297/multi-threaded-database-read-access)

Oracle JDBC interfaces as well as Oracle native drivers (i suppose) are capable of handling multithreaded requests ( http://www.cs.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/java.815/a64685/tips1.htm )

However when it comes to implementation in the database engine - this is not clear. From the current documentation my understanding is that as long as your request is READONLY with no intent to update no locking would occur and you should be seeing a performance boost (atleast minor).

There are many other factors however that determine whether the engine would use parallelism. The hardware config of the server (multi-core) etc can also determine if the query engine resorts to a parallel or queued approach.

Btw how much of timing difference are your observing in both approaches that you have tried. What was the magnitude of your data ?

Comment: As mentioned , the performance of fun2() degraded when fun1() was called in a thread . I have been using a dual core . The magnitude of the table is medium . The only difference , fun2 works on a View and fun1 works on the actual table

Answer (score 1):

Try to change isolation level to the READ COMMITTED and make queries with READ ONLY "clause". It should be less restrictive and allow you to read same tables simultaneously.

Comment: since I am using oracle the default isolation level is READ COMMITTED

Comment: If you are using READ COMMITTED isolation level and READONLY queries, and still see the problem, then I've just one reason to think of (so far): it MAY be because each (main and created) thread gets its data into Memory, then other thread comes, and swaps out this data into disk in order to bring its own data, then again other thread comes and swaps in data from disk so on - so memory thrashing. Can u please check memory usage with and without threads.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use two different connections. Multi-threading same connection accesing same table would always degrade performance, you are putting a stress in connection itself. You didn't say which driver you use for accessing, but I've tested a similar approach with JDBC driver in Oracle 10 and had performance degradation, I've guess that SQL commands are somewhat pipelined one after other if you use same connection.

Comment: How much degradation are you having? 5%, 10%, 80%? 10% or less is kind of acceptable, 80% of course is not. Can you share some code of your view?

Comment: @ ruhalde THe degradation is around 50 %

Comment: In that case, as your data is read-only (you are using a view) I'll try to materialize that view and set a job or something out of working hours to update that materialized view. We did that once with a huge product list table and worked just swell.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency always make you lose performance. You if need concurrency, you will have to live with this; If you don't need it, you shouldn't use it!

Some operations in SQL like "count" perform LOCKs in tables. Can you share your SQL?

Comment: even if I do a select on columns in different threads , does oracle lock the table ?